# Playing audio with Phaser

Tags: typescript, phaser-framework

Could anyone help me with the Phaser sound issue?
I have coded a button with a function that plays sound in TypeScript, but when I press the button on chrome, Phaser gives me the following warning on the chrome console:
`Phaser.Cache.getSound: Key "sample" not found in Cache.`
At first, I thought that the mp3 file has not been fully loaded when I pressed the button, but even when I wait enough amount of time, the situation is still the same...

```
export class PlayState extends Phaser.State {

    private sampleSound: Phaser.Sound;
    private testButton:  Phaser.Sprite;

    preload() {
      this.load.image("test", "assets/image/test.png")
      this.load.audio("sample", "assets/audio/sample.mp3");
    }

    create() {
      // Add test button
      this.testButton = this.add.sprite(50, 50, "test");
      this.testButton.anchor.setTo(0.5);
      this.testButton.inputEnabled = true;
      this.testButton.events.onInputDown.add(this.test);

      // Add audio
      this.sampleSound = this.add.audio("sample");
    }

    private test = () => {
      this.sampleSound.play();
    }
}
```

I certainly have the sample.mp3 file under assets/audio directory, so Phaser should be able to find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place the mp3 file **under the folder of the transpiled javascript file**. 
In my case, the TypeScript was looking for `source/assets/audio/sample.mp3`, but the transpiled javascript was looking for `dist/assets/audio/sample.mp3`.
(test.png was already there, so Phaser was able to find it. But I totally forgot to place the mp3 file...)

When you are using TypeScript, be always aware that scripts are executed after they are transpiled.

Answer (score 2):

Loading a sound file is one thing, having it decoded is another. Not sure why it gives a cache error, but what most probably happens is that you have the file loaded, but not yet decoded.

Try something like this:

```
export class PlayState extends Phaser.State {

    private sampleSound: Phaser.Sound;
    private testButton: Phaser.Sprite;

    preload() {
        this.load.image("test", "assets/image/test.png");
        this.load.audio("sample", "assets/audio/sample.mp3");
    }

    create() {
        // Add audio
        this.sampleSound = this.add.audio("sample");

        this.game.sound.setDecodedCallback(["sample"], this.createButton, this);
    }

    private createButton(): void {
        // Add test button
        this.testButton = this.add.sprite(50, 50, "test");
        this.testButton.anchor.setTo(0.5);
        this.testButton.inputEnabled = true;
        this.testButton.events.onInputDown.add(this.test);
    }

    private test = () => {
        this.sampleSound.play();
    }
}
```

This way you're only creating the button after the mp3 file is decoded. Add more keys to the first argument in case you need to load more sounds.

The lambda function that plays the sound can probably be a regular instance method (just for the sake of consistency).

Haven't tested it, but this should be it.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. The reason why I couldn't play sound was that the transpiled js file is looking for the different assets directory. After I placed the mp3 file for the js directory, the original code started working. This mp3 file is lite enough to run without checking decoded state, but I will use `setDecodedCallback` to make 100% sure audio file is decoded before using it. Thanks a lot for your help!